# Python : How and why is this syntax working ?  {1,2,3,4}

Tags: python, list, syntax, dictionary, set

As we know,

```
{} # Represents a dict
```

And

```
{'one': 1} # Again a dict
```

How and why is this a set :

```
{'one', 'two', 'three', 'four'} # I thought it should give syntax error
```

But it gives :

```
set(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']) # Strange ?? [ Should this happen ? ]
```

Can you provide a link to some official doc discussing the same ?

Comment: Dear down-voter, no offence in down-voting. Just add a comment what was missing / wrong with this ?

Comment: Can anyone know of any other wired / conflicting syntax in python ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Set literals](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#other-language-changes) are a 3.x feature that has been backported into 2.7.

This is a useful feature - note that set comprehensions are also allowed.

Comment: (And in Python 3, the set literal notation is also used in the `repr()` of a set, as opposed to what @YugalJindle is seeing in Python 2.7)

Comment: Hm, that comprehension feature is pretty cool. Thanks for sharing.